# Mongo duplicate key error on upsert or save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running into a problem inserting data into mongo via nodejs. I'm loading json objects into documents through either `upsert:true`, or `.save()` called on a returned mongoose document.

**EDIT:** I forgot to point out one important point, that this does work. I update 30-40,000 documents correctly. It will run for a while, then eventually throw this error. The "unique key (`xId`) is a different string each time, so I don't think it's caused by the data actually being loaded...

Here's the schema:

```
var rosterSchema = new Schema({
name        : String,
xId     : {type:String, unique: true},
event       : {type:ObjectId, ref:'Event'},
team        : {type:ObjectId, ref:'Team'},
division    : {type:ObjectId, ref:'Division'},
place       : String,
players     : [{type:ObjectId,ref:"Player"}],
staff       : [{type:ObjectId,ref:"Player"}],
matches     : [{type:ObjectId,ref:"Match"}],
});
```

Error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: r_fix.rosters index: xId_1 dup key: { : "6RNoYBSsCAJRsjxs" }
    at Function.MongoError.create
```

Each run of the parse/load function targets a single roster page, which references other rosters in their matches.

Most of the rosters already exist from loading other data.

I can't guarantee the order that the rosters will be parsed, so I may need to create a 'match' against a roster that doesn't exist yet, which requires the new roster to be created, hence why I use `findOneAndUpdate` as opposed to `find`

Any idea what might be causing this? I'm trying to avoid pasting the whole source so these are each of the individual calls, with what I believe to be relevant info:

```
var rosterObj = {
    xId     : id,
    name    : rosterJson.team_name,
};
Roster.findOneAndUpdate({xId:rosterObj.xId},{$set:rosterObj},{new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true})
    .exec((err,roster)=>{
        if(err)throw(err);

    }).then((roster)=>{

    ...
```

The above roster returns the document used in all subsequent `save()`'s

```
roster.event = event._id;
roster.save((err)=>{if(err)throw(err)})
```

...

```
roster.team = team._id;
roster.save((err)=>{if(err)throw(err)})
```

...

```
if(pObj.staff == "No")
        roster.players.addToSet(player._id);
    else
        roster.staff.addToSet(player._id);

    roster.save((err)=>{if(err)throw(err)});
```

...

```
if(!roster.event)
        if(oppRoster.event){
            roster.event = oppRoster.event;
            roster.save((err)=>{if(err)throw(err)});
        }
```

...

```
var rosterObj = {
    xId:mObj.vs.roster_id, 
    event:roster.event,
}    
Roster.findOneAndUpdate({xId:rosterObj.xId},{$set:rosterObj},{new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}).exec((err,oppRoster)=>{
        if(err)throw(err);

        return oppRoster;
    })
```

As far as I understand it, when I use a single key for the find, and it's the only `unique:true` value in the document, then `doc.save()` and `doc.findOneAndUpdate({ ... , {upsert :true...})` should never return a duplicate key error.

My `catch()` at the end of the promise chain doesn't catch these thrown errors either, but that is an entirely different problem.

But I don't know anything, so that's why I'm here!

EDIT: I should point out that I'm doing this over a large number of documents, but they're all promise-chained, so only one 'roster' should be getting updated at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique index constraint does not itself protect you from duplicate key errors, only from duplicate records. You need to catch the exception and retry. The duplicate key error should not reoccur as the race condition danger has passed at that point. See: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#behavior